# Crime Data Warehouse

Tags: data-warehouse, dimension, fact, measures

I am a IT student and now facing problem in understanding data warehousing. I need to implement a data warehouse that will be used in State police department for crime analysis. But I am not sure how to do with measure. I will use star schema. I want to set the business question from the view of Chief office , so I guess the measures should be No of crimes, No of offender and No of victims, and I am not sure..  May I know the fact table (measures).

Comment: And why would we do your homework for you, have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: One crime you should add to your data warehouse is laziness. The class of offenders most likely are school or uni students.

Comment: I have tried a lot..reading about whta are these and I dont have idea ..thats why I am asking ....I had made my table of content...and I understand about any others architecture or all...and only the thing i dont understand is how to create measures in fact table...I will use star schema...Plz dun judge without knowing details

Comment: This question is off-topic because it does not appear to have anything to do with programming.

Comment: This is data warehouse , Not programming @BoltClock

Comment: OK, well this site is for programming questions only. Try asking someone else, like your professor.

Comment: Ok..sorry ...I saw posts abt data warehouse dts why....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would start by writing down everything you know about crime. For example:Police, Detectives, Locations, CrimeType, Crime Instance etc.

Theses could be your tables.

Link the data in the tables to make it into a database. The data in the tables may be something like:

Location: Name, Address, Type, creationDate, user
Crime: Name, Severity, Punishment, creationDate, user
CrimeIntance: Crime, Location, Date, Detective, creationDate, user

etc, etc - use your imagination

Comment: Thanks...Yes I had done the tables but I am stuck with the measures...What I want is not answer....The logic How to think? There is 7 tables ; Fact table is Crime, Dimension tables will be Officer, Victim, Offender, Time, Location, case. I plan to use Location, case and time (Cube)

Comment: I dont know whether the view is correct or not...For example;
Chief officer - How many crimes happen by location/time.
No of prosecuted case/closed case.
Highest crime case/highest crime rate
Officer - Which police officer prosecuted the case?
similar offenders/victim for cases?

Comment: @Hikoe, you seem to be on the right track. Decide on you structure, measures and data then code it up. A plan and result is better than just a plan and much better than no plan at all.

Comment: Thank you...So, the measures I mentioned made sense?...yes I want to code...I know control files, data files and all, but can u suggest me any links or books there i can understand how to code for measures? Thank you...I was searching and already read the whole text book (Paulraj Ponniah ) given by my lecturer by there is no info about coding ...